# When training a variational Bayesian neural network in tfp, how can I visualize the evolution of the different terms in the loss separately?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow-probability

I want to use tensorflow-probability to train a simple fully-connected Bayesian Neural Network. The loss is composed of KL terms and a negative log likelihood term. How can I see their separate evolution with tfp?

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tfk = tf.keras
tfkl = tf.keras.layers
tfpl = tfp.layers
tfd = tfp.distributions

[make some data for a regression task]

input = tfkl.Input(n_features)
x = input
x = tfpl.DenseFlipout(100, activation='relu')(x)
x = tfpl.DenseFlipout(2)(x)
x = tfpl.DistributionLambda(lambda t: tfd.Normal(loc=t[..., :1],
                                                 scale=1e-3 + tf.math.softplus(t[..., 1:])))(x)

model = tfk.Model(input, x)

negloglik = lambda y, rv_y: -rv_y.log_prob(y)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(), loss=negloglik, metrics=['mse'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_val, y_val));
```

The loss function is the sum of the explicit term `negloglik` and a KL divergence term in each `DenseFlipout` layer (I can see those are there by looking at `model.losses`, for example).

How can I visualize each of these terms separately?

---

An attempt:

If I try to add a function that calculates `negloglik` to the metrics, such as

```
def negloglik_met(y_true, y_pred):
    return -y_pred.log_prob(y_true)
```

I get `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'log_prob'` which is confusing to me. `y_pred` should be the output of the `DistributionLambda` layer, so why is it a Tensor and not a Distribution?

Something else I hoped would work but does not is adding `model.losses[0]` to the metrics. There I get `ValueError: Could not interpret metric function identifier: Tensor("dense_flipout/divergence_kernel:0", shape=(), dtype=float32)`.

Comment: I also faced the same problem. See [https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/742](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/742). I think this is a bug (either in TF or TFP). It seems like TF assumes that the inputs to the loss function (that is also a metric in this case) are tensors, or, during the training process, a sample of the distribution is passed to this metric (the loss) rather than the distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I drilled down in the TensorFlow code. It's due to the automatic TensorFlow creating an automatic wrapper around your (lambda) function. It casts and reshapes the model output (the distribution) to the type of the metric (which seems odd to me anyways). So, to prevent it, you should create your own wrapper, that doesn't perform this cast. The code that does this, is at: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py#L583

So inspire yourself on that block of code to make your own Metric Wrapper. This should be a feature of TFP.

Comment: I'm accepting this, partly because the code you left at https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/issues/742#issuecomment-580433644 does solve this for me. Unfortunately it doesn't allow me to set metrics that depend on the weight values instead of the final predictions, such as the KL divergence above (though here I can work it out by knowing the total loss and the negative log likelihood, that's not generic).